# Equation $e^{\frac{1}{x}} - x =0$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Can someone solve this equations with steps

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}} - x =0$$

I dont know how to start. I tried adding logarithms but that doesn't help.

Comment: Do you accept numerical solution?

Comment: You cannot solve this equation exactly with just algebraic rearrangement. You will need to find an approximate solution using a numerical or graphical method.

Comment: you can find a solution on $]-\infty ,0]$ if you set $f(0)=0$ (because $\lim_{x\to 0^-}(e^{1/x}-x)=0$. But not on all $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Lambert W-Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)? x = 1/W(1)

Comment: @idm ?? There is a real solution in $(1,2)$.

Comment: But if you don't know (or want to use) the Lambert W-Function you can solve this numerically using Newton's method; it converges rather quickly with a suitable starting approximation.

Comment: Could we use Lagrange inversion theorem here? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Lambert_W_function c.f. also @ PM's comment and @ Lukas' answer.

Comment: As far as I understand: The inversion theorem justifies the existence of such a function. After this, the inverse function was just given a name, so the “hard work”, if any, would rather result in showing that the theorem applies.

Answer (score 9):

This equation cannot be solved using “traditional” algebraic manipulations.
In this case, one would use the *Lambert W function*: $$W(x): x = W(x)\cdot e^{W(x)}$$ or in other words, it is the solution of the equation $x = w e^w$.

With this knowledge, we can try to substitute $y:=\frac{1}{x}$:

$$\Rightarrow 0 = e^y-\frac{1}{y} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{y} = e^y \Rightarrow 1 = y\cdot e^y\\ \Rightarrow y = W(1)\Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{W(1)} $$

See further [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

EDIT:
I just want to add the following: Some people tend to say this would be a trick and no real solution, because this is like saying “I don't know the solution, so I will assign it a name” — but technically, that's exactly what is done when defining the (square) root!

Once we know that the inverse of a function exists (in this case this can be verified using the [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem#Lambert_W_function)), we can define some function to be the solution, even if we define it just *implicitly* by its properties, and call this a *solution* with full legitimacy.

But however, that's just my two cents.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone. I'll google a bit for this Lambert function.

Comment: FWIW, $x \approx 1.763222834351896710225201776951707080436017986667473634570456905547275847186995736789083891050681105561933002027405468046737640$

Comment: @Djole you might want to Mark my answer as accepted by clicking on the green tick, it supports me by giving me reputation.